# Connecting to Database on Virtual Machine?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jdbc, database-connection, virtual-machine

Simple question can a Java service layer running on Tomcat7 on a host machine connect to persistent data store (mySQL) running inside a virtual box with portforwarding? I want to know if the hibernate or Jdbc connection strings from host machine work if mySQL server is installed inside a VirtualBox.

Also if it does work can I expect behavioral deviations in terms of speed and connection pooling if everything is packaged into one single system and deployed in a real world web server in a single enviroment?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, it is possible and will work. You will likely have to play with the firewall settings on your virtual box instance. You don't specify OS, so it's hard to tell you what exactly you'll need to tweak.

As far as deploying this in a real-world environment, if you mean production, you probably should NOT do that. This is a great setup to build on, but not something I would run in production.

To be clear, there won't be any issues behaviorally speaking, it will act as MySQL always acts, but it will absolutely be slower than running it on 'bare metal' -- how much slower will vary based on hardware, workload, etc. and it is generally not a great design for a production deployment..

Comment: Thanks for your response. To fill in the missing details you were referring to, the server of choice is ubuntu server 12.x. And no I wont have it running inside VM when I deploy it to prod server running on 'bare metal', however I want to be sure that its behavior wont show deviation once its taken out of VM Box and made to sit on the bare metal.

Comment: So, for DEV ONLY, you can do sudo ufw disable to turn off the firewall. THIS IS DANGEROUS, only do it for DEV! You won't see any deviation when you deploy, the only thing you'll see is better performance because bare metal = faster :)